# What's the correct translation for this sloka which is used for Ghanta Puja

Tags: translation-request, puja, shloka

While reading through the purvanga kramas of Sri Vishnu Pooja vidhi laid down by Sri Jayatirtha in the padhyamala, i have come across the below verse.

[image: IMage of Shloka in Devanagari]

> Āgamārthaṃ tu devānāṃ gamanārthaṃ tu rakṣasām ।
>   kuru ghaṇṭāravaṃ tatra devatāhvāna lā'ñchanam |15|
>
> ajñānatho'jñānatovāpi kāṃsya ghaṃṭān navādayet |16|
>   rākṣasānāṃ piśācānāṃ taddeśe vasatirbhavet ।
>   tasmāt sarva prayatnena ghaṃṭāmAvadayettataH |17|

Can someone help out with the translation (into english) from line 3 onwards, i.e., from "ajnAnAjjnAnato.." upto the last line ending with verse 17.

Comment: What's the special significance of the title? A Ghantapuja is done only as a Puja Purvanga.. Nobody worships the Ghanta otherwise..

Comment: Purvanga pujas are meant as preparatory acts. If they are not done properly, the fruit of the puja, be it fulfillment of desire or Antarkarana Shuddhi, cannot be in full. So, from the learning I have, all rituals need very careful preparation to be highly efficacious. Hence the importance of Ghanta puja.

Comment: I know what's Purvanga Puja.. But Ghanta Puja is not a standalone Puja.. it's done only as Purvanga.. so that's why i asked why the special need of mentioning "Ghantapuja as purvanga "..getting my point now? Your title should be something like - "What's the correct translation for this sloka which is used for Ghanta Puja?"

Comment: Okay .. am fine with the suggested edit, as translation is what I really wanted ..

Comment: You should also write the shloka present in the image. Image doesn't work for all and all can't read Devanagari.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the answer (did not want to delete the query), but this led to a larger question.

First 2 lines (literally) translate to;

> For welcoming the gods and for driving away evil spirits, sound
>   the bell there, (which is) a token of invoking / inviting gods.

Please note that the above verse is a *Mantra* and has to be read in the Anustup chanda style of chanting.

The next 3 lines (literally translate as below:

> Our of ignorance or also out of being aware, never sound a bell made
>   of Brass/Bronze, for that becomes the residence of Rakshasa and
>   Pisacha. From that (reason), by all means, never sound (such a)bell
>   like that.

Please note that the above lines is more of a prohibitive instruction.

It is interesting to note that jayatirtha prohibits the usage of brass/bronze bells for worship. Most houses and even temples (that i have observed) use them. So, such a prohibition being made by Jayatirtha OR such a point being missed out by many temples is a very puzzling indeed.

I am fairly confident of this translation, so this would lead to larger questions such as the consequence of using a kaNsya (brass/bronze) ghanta (bell), who is the recipient of the offerings of poojas and the like.