# Why kANsya(Brass/Bronze) is prohibited in ghanta(bell) pooja?

Tags: mantras, translation-request, puja, shloka

I read this question [Ghanta Puja](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/27706/whats-the-correct-translation-for-this-sloka-which-is-used-for-ghanta-puja) and the translation provided for the following sloka in question says that ringing kaNsya(Brass/Bronze) bell make the place residence of Rakshasa and Pisacha. But today everyone use only Brass/Bronze bells, so why this sloka is contradicting to today's belief:

[image: Image of shloka in Devanagari]

> Āgamārthaṃ tu devānāṃ gamanārthaṃ tu rakṣasām ।
>   kuru ghaṇṭāravaṃ tatra devatāhvāna lā'ñchanam |15|
>
> ajñānatho'jñānatovāpi kāṃsya ghaṃṭān navādayet |16|
>   rākṣasānāṃ piśācānāṃ taddeśe vasatirbhavet ।
>   tasmāt sarva prayatnena ghaṃṭānādaṃ prakārayet |17|

Comment: @Sarvabhouma I am not good in typing devanagari can you help in editing ?